# How view data that comes from a .GZ File Format on ORACLE SQL?

Tags: sql, linux, oracle, unix

### EXPLANATION OF MY CONDITION AND PROBLEM I AM FIGURING

I find this a bit too complicated, maybe because I am new to this event and the world of LINUX.

1. So I am here on my PC (WINDOWS 7) then I need to make a sql based reporting site but the data I need is not in oracle yet.
2. I need to view the data in oracle sql that comes from many files from another controller -> another PC (UNIX).
3. The format of the file is originally .gz but physically its FILE FORMAT is like this machinedump.log.gz05052012 (Its still .gz -> inside is a .log but still a .txt content)

Note: that controller/personal computer that I am connecting has a username, password and port number.

Inside each .log.gz data it has a data like:

```
20120806_161944: 08.06 16:17:29.574 t_cm_03 C3011099140000 at_sts       =    0 
20120806_161944: 08.06 16:17:29.574 t_cm_03 C3011099140000 at_sts       =    1
20120806_161944: 08.06 16:17:29.574 t_cm_03 C3011099140000 at_sts       =    2
20120806_161944: 08.06 16:17:29.574 t_cm_03 C3011099140000 at_sts       =    3
20120806_161944: 08.06 16:17:29.574 t_cm_03 C3011099140000 at_sts       =    4 
20120806_161944: 08.06 16:17:29.574 t_cm_03 C3011099140000 at_sts       =    5
20120806_161944: 08.06 16:17:29.574 t_cm_03 C3011099140000 at_sts       =    6
20120806_161944: 08.06 16:17:29.574 t_cm_03 C3011099140000 at_sts       =    7
```

But there is a more bigger problem too that I see:
The MACHINEDUMP.LOG.GZ files are many like:

```
machinedump.log.gz05052012
machinedump.log.gz05062012
machinedump.log.gz05072012
machinedump.log.gz05082012
etc.
```

### So here is QUESTION and HELP NEED to my problem:

1. I wanna ask you guys what is the best way to store these file contents into a single table?
   from those .LOG.GZ files to a single Table?
2. Regarding on the 1st question, is it too possible to make the data fetching based on the "date" automated?
   Meaning if there is a file that match the present date, it would execute and save those data to desired table?
3. Is there a way you guys could show me what to do?
4. In addition guys, is there anything here that I must study deeply?

I need to make these data a usefull and readable report on using atleast SQL(oracle or is there any better way) and NETBEANS to do the rest of the job(These I know).

### MODERATORS

Is it possible to have my previous failed Question DELETED? Thanks...

Comment: Why duplicating the already closed question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/16504326/298282

Comment: I FIXED IT. Its messed up and ended to be closed.

Comment: Well, this question has exactly the same meaningless content. And I still don't understand what is your question.

Comment: I even fixed the question from last. Its edited. But closed so I made a new one.

Comment: Generally logs are archived in compressed form to save space and scanned with a tool using regular expression patterns or other text matching criteria. The summarized results of such a scan can then be stored in a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say which version of Oracle you're using.  This matters because Oracle adds new capabilities to its arsenal with each release.  The following solution will work on 11.0.1.7 (i.e. the last patch release of 11gR1) or later; earlier versions require more wrangling.

But first:

Do you need to stiore this information in a table?   Will it be sufficient to read it once?  Because a relational database like Oracle is not the best fit for storing machine logs.  There are plenty of free (or free-ish) document DBs which might be much better suited - MongoDB, Cassandra, etc.  Or there's Splunk which is intended for just that.

Anyway, the first way to read files inthe database is to build an external table over the file.  This is just like a reguilar table except the data is in an OS file rather than tablespace. In 11gR2 Oracle introduced the `preprocessor` clause, which allows us to associate a shell script with the table, which is run before the SELECT statement executes.  This is particularly pertinent in your case, because you can use the preprocessor script to uncompress your file.

So the basic workflow is:

1. A script which locates a GZ file in one directory, unzips it to a file with a standard name.
2. An external table whioch reads from the standard name file and which has that script as its preprocess script
3. An INSERT statement which selects from the external table and writes to your target table

A more precise version of this will require more details than you have given regarding your business rules, but you should be able to figure it out for yourself.

Find out more on External Tables [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_concepts.htm#SUTIL011).

Read Adrian Billington's excellent articles on preprocessor scripts [here](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=512) and [here](http://www.oraclhttp://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=513e-developer.net/display.php?id=513).